# "sharp" module issue while launching Appium v2.0.0-rc.3 from mac terminal

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-desktop, appium-java

I have been facing same issue due to 'sharp' module when I try to launch appium server from mac terminal.
[image]

**Software Versions**:

- Mac 13.4 (22F66)
- Processor 1.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
- Appium v2.0.0-rc.3
- Java 11
- Node 20.3.0
- NPM 9.7.1
- uiautomator2@2.26.1

**Exception**:

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v2.0.0-rc.3
[Appium] Attempting to load driver uiautomator2...
[debug] [Appium] Requiring driver at 
/Users/manish/.appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver
[Appium] Could not load driver 'uiautomator2', so it will not 
be available. Error in loading the driver was: 
[Appium] Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module
[Appium] Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-darwin- 
 x64.node'
[Appium] Require stack:
[Appium] - /Users/manish/.appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js
```

**Below is What I have tried:**

1. Uninstalling Appium v1.22.3 and then installing Appium 2.0
2. Updating Node and Npm version to their latest versions.
3. Appium server error says to install sharp using “npm install --platform=darwin --arch=x64 sharp” but after successful installation also I am getting same issue.
4. Checked official sharp version to check the compatibility, it looks ok to me. https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#prebuilt-binaries
5. Tried to install sharp-cli. “npm i sharp-cli”.
6. Tried to install sharp globally using an admin account.
7. Updated homebrew also ran brew upgrade.
8. changed permissions in of node_module.
9. Uninstalled sharp and reinstalled it globally and also rebuild it.
   npm uninstall sharp
   npm install -g sharp
   npm cache clean --force
   sudo npm rebuild sharp

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling driver? and reinstalling it?

1. `appium driver uninstall uiautomator2`
2. `appium driver install uiautomator2`

Comment: Yes I tried npm uninstall appium-uiautomator2-driver but it did not work either after reinstalling. The command which you mentioned gives error -- Error: npm command 'uninstall appium-uiautomator2-driver' failed with code 190